# I've found a GeoKret, what can I do with it?

Tags: geocaching

The previous founder wrote in cache log that he had dropped a trackable called **GeoKret**. I've found it, but I don't know how to log it? I can't find it on GC site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**GeoKret** is an open alternative to commercial TravelBugs. It is an independent solution, having own site: geokrety.org, where you can log it.

It is integrated with **OpenCaching** portal, but Groundspeak is not willing to integrate them with their site. You can use Chrome plugin called [GeoKrety Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geokrety-toolbox/ldbheajkebdflbjdckojokbfdndkahnl).

Registering new GeoKret costs you nothing, but you need to print a label yourself and laminate it. There are a few templates for labels available, my favourite has QR code which directs the founder directly to the site where he can log the GeoKret.

[image: A GeoKret posing near beautiful cache]